# How to use azure blob in lumen?

Tags: laravel, azure, lumen, azure-blob-storage, lumen-5.4

I need to use azure blob storage but the problem is i cann't find any reference or tutorial to apply azure blob storage in Lumen.

I only find azure blob in laravel.
Here what i found,

https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2016/10/24/creating-an-azure-storage-adapter-for-laravel/

I don't know how to put the code to config/filesystem.php, i cann't find it in Lumen Framework.

Would you like to give me some reference?
Any help would appreciate.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my [research](https://gist.github.com/deividaspetraitis/4cca4fa6a61cc9a75e12f640041e53f5), By default lumen doesn't support laravel file system. In order to integrate to lumen,you could follow these instructions

- composer require league/flysystem
- Copy filesystems config file from Laravel (
  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php
  ) to your local Lumen installation document_root/config
- Bind filesystem to IoC for example in document_root/bootstrap/app.php
  by adding this code lines:

  $app->singleton('filesystem', function ($app) { return $app->loadComponent('filesystems', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'filesystem'); });

Then you could be able to access `filesystem` by calling app('filesystem') and use it as using in Laravel.

Please refer to another case: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/168

Try to simulate this [github source code](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage) to add disk configuration:

```
 'azure' => [
            'driver'    => 'azure',
            'name'      => env('AZURE_STORAGE_NAME'),
            'key'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'),
            'container' => env('AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER'),
 ],
```

In addition, i found a package named [league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage](https://packagist.org/packages/league/flysystem-azure-blob-storage),you could try it to replace `league/flysystem`

Comment: hi, what is IoC ?

Comment: @JoshParinussa Thank you for your Adoption,please refer to this blog about IOC in php:https://medium.com/@NahidulHasan/laravel-ioc-container-why-we-need-it-and-how-it-works-a603d4cef10f